# How to use dcast() to convert a 5x2 data.table to a 1x5 data.tabe?

Tags: r, data.table, dcast

I have the following data.table

```
DT

ABBREVIATION    FULL_TEXT
-----------------------------
    DCD         TEXT1
    PCK         TEXT2
    KLM         TEXT3
    NOP         TEXT4
    XYZ         TEXT5
```

I would like to transform the data.table such that each "ABBREVIATION" is it's own column name. And there's one row that details the "FULL_TEXT", so

```
DCD     PCK     KLM     NOP     XYZ
------------------------------------
TEXT1   TEXT2   TEXT3   TEXT4   TEXT5
```

I tried using

```
dcast(DT, FULL_TEXT ~ ABBREVIATION, value.var = "FULL_TEXT")
```

but that doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dcast(df, 1 ~ ABBREVIATION, value.var = 'FULL_TEXT')[, -1, with = FALSE]
#      DCD   KLM   NOP   PCK   XYZ
# 1: TEXT1 TEXT3 TEXT4 TEXT2 TEXT5
```

You should use transpose instead though

```
data.table::transpose(df, make.names = 'ABBREVIATION')
#      DCD   PCK   KLM   NOP   XYZ
# 1: TEXT1 TEXT2 TEXT3 TEXT4 TEXT5
```

Data used

```
df <- fread('
ABBREVIATION    FULL_TEXT
    DCD         TEXT1
    PCK         TEXT2
    KLM         TEXT3
    NOP         TEXT4
    XYZ         TEXT5
')
```